# Send udp packet to local networks from html

Tags: javascript, html, udp

I have a program running on a local computer listening for UDP packets on a specific port. I would like a website that when a user presses a button, a UDP packet gets sent from this device locally without any 3rd party servers or computers interacting with it. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not support anything other than HTTP, HTTPS and sometimes FTP, RTSP. You can't use different application layer protocol. You can't use UDP.

If you control the client, you could create a custom MIME type, associate it with a program on the client which sends the packet and serve it up from your website.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will have to figure out another way to make this work thank :)